# Каким способом лучше всего перезаписать строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Я пишу программу, которая шифрует текст. Какой из способов предпочтительней для записи видоизмененного значения в новую строку?

**1 способ:**

```
string_ = "Hello"
result = list() # здесь будет результат

for i in string_:
    letter = do_sth_with_letter(i) # видоизменяем букву
    result.append(letter)

result = "".join(result)
```

или

**2 способ:**

```
string_ = "Hello"
result = str() # здесь будет результат

for i in string_:
   letter = do_sth_with_letter(i) # видоизменяем букву
   result += letter
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Второй ваш способ будет тормозить на длинных строках. Первый способ быстрее, там только лишнее копирование данных.

Вот способ быстрый и без лишних копий:

```
string_ = "Hello"
result = ''.join(map(do_sth_with_letter, string_))
```

Comment: Спасибо, этот способ, к тому же, более элегантный)

Answer (score 4):

Как общее правило - **никогда не конкатенируйте строки**, и не только в Питоне. В большинстве языков программирования **строки иммутабельны**, то есть неизменяемы, поэтому когда вы добавляете что-то в строку, интерпретатор не может ничего дописать в старую строку, а должен создать новую строку. Создание нового объекта - это всегда большие накладные расходы. Нужно выделить память, скопировать в неё данные. Если строка, в которую идёт добавление, длинная, это уже выливается в заметные потери времени на копирование этой строки в новый объект.

Когда же вы добавляете что-то в список, то это совершенно нормальное действие, список - это как-раз такой вид коллекции, который изначально предназначен для того, чтобы в него что-то постоянно добавлять.